# How do I merge 3 variables in r into a single single variable

Tags: r

how do I combine 3 variables with similar values into 1 variable.I wan to combine the 3 product category into a single product category, the values inside are IDs.
[image]

edit:
[This is my expected output, this graph is for only Product_Category 1. The end result should look similar but with counts for all 3 product category combine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFQdf.png)

Comment: can you share some expected output?

Comment: @JaneIsDepressed It would be useful if you could provide some example input and also the expected output. :) For instance, it's unclear what you mean by "combine...into a single category." Would this mean that the new, merged category would contain `1, 6, 14` in the second row?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to include the output that I am looking for, see my reply below for a clearer explanation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to characters.

```
Product_Category_1 <- as.character(Product_Category_1)
Product_Category_2 <- as.character(Product_Category_2)
Product_Category_3 <- as.character(Product_Category_3)
```

Then paste them together using a separator.

```
DF$Product_Categories <- paste(Var1, Var2, Var3, sep = "-")
```

Then convert new variable into a factor.

```
DF$Product_Categories <- as.factor(DF$Product_Categories)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, my objective is to get the total count for say '6' from all 3 product categories and plotting them into a single chart. So the chart will display the total number of '6' from all 3 product categories.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a clearer description of what you want. For instance, your picture indicates "A, B, C" but there's no clear indication of what that is.

Regardless, this seems closer to what you're getting at:

```
DF<-data.frame(replicate(3, sample(1:10, 100, replace = T)))

names(DF) <- c('Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3')
barplot(t(sapply(DF, table)), beside = T)
```

[image]